# pushing DICT None to SQL Null

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have this piece of code:

```
def get_summary_data(self):
    summary_data = self.page_data.find('table', {'class': 'GroupBox1'})
    record = {}
    rows = summary_data.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        fields = row.findAll('td')
        for field in fields:
            key = field.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
            value = field.find('strong').text.strip() if field.find('strong') else None
            value = value if value else None
            if key != '':
                record[self.configuration[key]] = value
    ins_qry = "INSERT INTO {tablename} ({columns}) VALUES {values};".format(
        tablename='rrc_completion_data.summarydata',
        columns=', '.join(record.keys()),
        values=tuple(record.values())
    )
    self.engine.execute(ins_qry)
```

The query this generates looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO rrc_completion_data.summarydata (Track_No, Status, Operator_Nm, Compl_Type, Field_Nm, Completion_Dt, Lease_Nm, Filing_Purpose, District_No, Well_Type, LeaseNo, County, Well_No, WellBore_Profile, API, WB_Compl_Type, DrilL_Permit_No, SL_Parent_Drill_Permit_No, Field_No, Horiz_Depth_Severance) VALUES ('2928', 'Work in Progress', 'WILLIAMS PROD. GULF COAST, L.P. (924558)', 'New Well', 'NEWARK, EAST (BARNETT SHALE)', '05/17/2010', 'DR. BOB SMITH A NORTH', 'Initial Potential', '09', 'Producing', None, 'DENTON', '10H', 'HORIZONTAL', '42-121-33861', None, '687311', None, '65280200', None);
```

As you can see, there are values of None that I'm trying to use as Nulls.  but results in this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "none" does not exist
LINE 1: ...A NORTH', 'Initial Potential', '09', 'Producing', None, 'DEN...
```

What am I missing?  My intent is to have nulls in the database table where None exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problems is using string formatting to pass values to an SQL query. **Never** do that. It exposes you to SQL injection, among other things. It seems that you whitelist the columns, which is good, but then pass the values wrapped in a Python `tuple` and trust that the string representation matches that of an SQL row construct — which is not true, as can be seen already with the `None` values. Another source of problems would be strings containing a `'` character.

Instead you should use placeholders in the query string and let your libraries handle passing the values to SQL:

```
columns = list(record.keys())
ins_qry = "INSERT INTO rrc_completion_data.summarydata ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})".format(
    columns=', '.join(columns),
    placeholders=', '.join([':' + c for c in columns])
)
self.engine.execute(text(ins_qry), record)
```

Comment: Thanks my friend.  This helps alot.